# Botão para adicionar um novo campo

Tags: java, android, array, xml, tabela-html

Estou criando uma aplicação que calcula a média de 3 números, até ai tudo bem, mas agora queria criar um botão '+' que na hora que eu clicasse nele ele adicionasse um novo campo e fizesse esse cálculo com o quarto e assim por diante... Porém não achei nada que fosse parecido ou que fizesse isso, gostaria da ajuda de vocês para isso.

Answer (score 3):

Para adicionar elementos programaticamente em seu layout, você precisa instanciar o `Widget` (`TextView`, `EditText`, `Button` e etc) e adicionar ao container usando o método [`addView(View view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) ou [`addView(View view, LayoutParams params)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).

Esse comportamento de compor hierarquia e adicionar `View's` é característico da classe [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), podemos associar um `ViewGroup` a uma árvore de `View's`. Exemplos dela seriam: `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` e os demais.

Um exemplo de adição programatica de novos `Widgets` seria:

```
// Aqui entra o seu container, pai dos elementos
// Basta escolher algum que pertenca ao seu layout.
// Recomendo um LinearLayout com orientation="vertical"
ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.container);
// Ou
ViewGroup container = getView().findViewById(R.id.container);

// Iremos instanciar o novo Widget a ser adicionado
// Em sua Activity
EdiText novoEdit = new EdiText(this);
// Ou em um Fragment
EditText novoEdit = new EditText(getActivity());

// Dependendo de como for seu layout, podem haver outros edits que nao
// estao relacionados com a soma diretamente, para sabermos que ele
// foi adicionado programaticamente, colocamos uma marcacao
novoEdit.setTag(R.id.container, true);

// Se quiser setar um texto inicial
novoEdit.setText("42");

// Se quiser adicionar um Hint que aparecerá quando nenhum texto for digitado
novoEdit.setHint("Entre com o numero");

// Aqui adicionamos o Widget ao container
container.addView(novoEdit);
// Ou
// Aqui pode variar um pouco dependendo da subclasse do container
container.addView(novoEdit, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Para somar os valores:

```
// Aqui novamente entra o seu container, pai dos elementos
ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.container);

// Quantos filhos ele tem
int childCount = container.getChildCount();

// Itero sobre os filhos do container
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
    // Pegamos o filho no indice i
    View filho = container.getChildAt(i);

    // Se ele for um EditText
    if(filho instanceof EditText) {
        EditText editFilho = (EditText) filho;

        // Eh um EditText criado programaticamente?
        // Para isso verificamos a marcacao que fizemos
        if(editFilho.getTag(R.id.container) != null) {

            String texto = editFilho.getText().toString();

            // TODO Fazer tratamento de vazio e de exception...
            // TODO Usar o texto para fazer a media... 
        }
    }
}
```