# Como compor um Layout Linear na Activity usando JAVA apenas

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Em minha aplicação possui um layout linear vertical com o id:

```
@+id/items
```

Neste layout para cada item contido em uma lista, eu gostaria de criar outro Layout Linear horizontal chamado, Row contendo 2 ImageButton e um EditText, um ImageButton ao ser clicado removeria o item atual, outro marcaria o item como correto.

XML da Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.leonardo.quiz.QuestionFormActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_media"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ipt_media"
    android:src="@drawable/question" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ipt_value"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_media"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ipt_value"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ></LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_add"
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/items"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_back"
    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_add"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_exit"
    android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_back"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_save"
    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Contudo, qual a maneira correta de preencher este LinearLayout  inteiramente em JAVA, 
lembrando que nele terá outro LinearLayout contendo ImageButton e EditText.

Comment: Você terá que criar esses elementos baseados em uma lista? Se sim, um `ListView` não atende a sua necessidade? Caso contrário, dê uma olhada nessas respostas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35636/como-adicionar-um-imageview-em-um-relativelayout-em-runtimer/35638#35638:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32225/botão-para-adicionar-um-novo-campo/32244#32244 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35636/como-adicionar-um-imageview-em-um-relativelayout-em-runtimer/35638#35638 e veja se não atende.

Comment: Na verdade prefiro não usar um ListView, e a View items deve aumentar com o numero de items e não deve ser rolante

Comment: Então terá que fazer a adição programaticamente. Dê uma olhada nessas duas perguntas/respostas para ver se já não responde sua pergunta.

Comment: Ja estou conseguindo criar programaticamente, porém a ImageButton precisa ter um tamanho especifico, como faço isso , usando o LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo real:

```
private ViewGroup createAlphabetTrack() {
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (30 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tv_title);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams textparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textparams.weight = 1;
        final int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int iterate = 0;
        if (height >= 1024){
            iterate = 1; layout.setWeightSum(26);
        } else {
            iterate = 2; layout.setWeightSum(13);
        }
        for (char character = 'a'; character <= 'z'; character+=iterate) {
            final TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity());
            textview.setLayoutParams(textparams);
            textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            textview.setText(Character.toString(character));
            layout.addView(textview);
        }

        return layout;
    }
```

Todos os atributos são setados via código.

Para finalizar, você pega o linear criado e adiciona em outra view.

Se for num fragment, você pode fazer:

```
ViewGroup.class.cast(getView()).addView(sua view criada);
```

Ou

```
  [sua View Group].addView([sua view criada]);
```